# Parameter variable schema oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm newbie using Oracle.

I have a question: in SQL Server, we can use:

```
DECLARE DBNAME1 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE DBNAME2 VARCHAR(20)

SET @DBNAME1 ='TEST_DB'
SET @DBNAME2 ='TEST_DB2'

INSERT INTO @DBNAME1.TABLECORE
    SELECT * 
    FROM @DBNAME2.TABLENONCORE T
```

What is the equivalent of this script in `if @DBNAME == Schema` in Oracle?

Comment: In Oracle static sql you cannot use a variable able names, columns, etc. You need to use he actual schema name and table. So in his case
Insert into test_db.tablecore ...
select * from test_db2.ablecore t ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can manage it but creating `db link` on `dbname2` :

```
create public database link dbname2 connect to myschema using 'abc-scan.mycompany.com.tr:1521/dbname2.mycompany.com.tr';
```

and calling the following dml statement from `dbname1` :

```
insert into tablecore select * from tablenocore@dbname2;
```