# How to create a database link from Oracle database to DB2 on system i

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2-400

I'm trying to establish a connection to a DB2 database using a database link in Oracle.

The final objective is to be able to do a "create table XXX as select * from YYY@DB2"

I can connect directly to the DB2 database using SQL Developer and the db2jcc.jar connector but i can't create the database link.

Additionaly, when i use the feature "Migrate to Oracle..." on SQL Developer it just dump a java exception.

Thanks in advance,
Manuel

Comment: I don't know about creating links for DB2 from Oracle, but perhaps this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745686/parameter-variable-schema-oracle/47747366#47747366 among two oracle databases may help.

Comment: Hi Barbaros. What should be the connection string for thmy case?

Comment: Have you tried googling `oracle db2 dblink`?  One of the results https://mark.the-fennells.org/2011/08/23/using-a-dblink-in-oracle-to-connect-to-an-ibm-db2-database/

Comment: Hi Charles.  I looked into that and my OS is not Unix.

Comment: @Manuel `'abc-scan.mycompany.com.tr:1521/dbname2.mycompany.com.tr'` in the first string for public dblink stand for connection.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is with "heterogenous services", ie, Oracle takes via ODBC to a remote non-oracle data source.

There's a manual for this in the standard doc set:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/heter/index.html

but in a nutshell, the basic steps are:

1) have an ODBC driver for DB2 on your database server, or on a machine that your database server can reach.

2) Configure an ODBC target for that DB2 database.  Lets call it "MYDB2"

3) create a file initMYDB2.ora in $ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin.  Configure it as per the sample (init4g4odbc.ora).  It points to your MYDB2 target.

4) In that directory, you'll also find samples for listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

So you'll end up with a tnsnames entry called "MYDB2".  It will reference the initMYDB2.ora, which will point to the MYDB2 odbc target, which will be your DB2 database.

Then you create a database link in the normal way:

```
create database link blah
connect to my_db2_user
identified by my_db2_password
using 'mydb2';
```

Hope this helps.